# How to align the Plasma TV Display connected to a Mac notebook?

Tags: mac, display, macbook, plasma-tv

I've got an oldish mac notebook (eg. not an intel based one). Works fine. I connect it to my plasma tv via a dvi->hdmi cable. Instantly it recognises stuff, displays flash on and off and finally the tv has the 2nd screen. kewl :)

Problem is this... the picture displayed on the TV is not aligned correctly. Is there any way I can fix up this alignment? I've tried changing the resolution for the 2nd display (which works) but it's still not aligned right.

Is there some secret setting so i can move the picture on the display to the right a bit and shrink the overall picture size a wee bit.

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way will be to actually use a program like [DisplayConfigX](http://www.3dexpress.de/) to set your resolution (if it isn't recognizing it correctly) and to handle the Overscan accordingly. ([Example instructions on correcting Overscan](http://www.peterkrantz.com/2007/mac-mini-overscan/))

That said, before you try DisplayConfigX - have you gone to the Displays Preference Pane in System Preferences and checked out the "Options" tab on the window that will appear on the TV (assuming spanned desktop). In the options tab there are two checkboxes - one labelled "Best for Video" and another one labelled "Overscan". See if those options will help you out. (Sorry I can't find a screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

I have and LG LG TV and a Mac Book Pro running 10.6.  What I did was adjust my TV settings by going home->picture->(scroll all the way down to the bottom) Screen RGB-PC -> Position  and then adjust TV Screen position.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to adjust the picture settings on the TV itself rather than the Macbook.

Comment: I was afraid of that... but I couldn't find any way how to do that :( I went through the entire tv menu system for fine tuning the picture. it's always just the normal colour/contrast/brightness, etc. :(

Comment: I don't know about your specific TV, but on mine there is a separate submenu for PC monitor settings.. Anything like that on yours?

Comment: nope :( i've looked everywhere.